# Bitfinex API V2: place MARKET order error: Invalid order: not enough tradable balance

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to place new MARKET order in Bitfinex V2 NodeJs API, but always getting **Invalid order: not enough tradable balance.**
I have U$ 150.00 in my wallet. Thought the Website I can place the order, but by Javascript Node API, I can't!

Can anyone help me, pleasse?

```
  module.exports.placedOrder = function(_symbol, _amount, callback) {

    ws.on('error', (err) => {
      ws.close();
      return  callback(err);
    });

    ws.on('open', () => {
      ws.auth();
    });

    ws.once('auth', () => {

      const order = new Order({
        cid: Date.now(),
        type: Order.type.MARKET,
        symbol: _symbol,
        amount: _amount
      }, ws);

      // Enable automatic updates
      order.registerListeners();

      order.on('update', () => {
        console.log('ordem atualizada: %j', order.serialize());
      });

      order.on('close', () => {
        console.log('ordem fechada. STATUS = %s', order.status);
        ws.close();
        return  callback(null, createOrderObj(order.serialize())); 
      });

      console.log(LOG_PREFIX + 'conexão autenticada, enviando ordem de CID: %d', order.cid);

      order.submit().then(() => {
        console.log(LOG_PREFIX + 'ordem submetida com sucesso. ID: %d, CID: [%d]', order.cid, order.id);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(LOG_PREFIX + 'ERROR AO SUBMETER ORDEM: '+ err);
        ws.close();
      });
    });

    ws.open();
  };
```

Comment: I just fixed the error after a wide set of try-and-error, by changing the order type to **Order.type.EXCHANGE_MARKET**.